# git clone shows "invalid username or password" for different repository

Tags: git, github

```
$ git clone https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenUSD.git
Cloning into 'OpenUSD'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/org/repo.git/'
```

The URL in the `git clone` command is for the OpenUSD repository, but the error message is for a different repository, which belongs to my own private repository.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `remote.origin.url` is set to the my private repository I referenced earlier.

I resolved the issue by unsetting it using the following command:

```bash
git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.url
```

To verify the `remote.origin.url`, I executed the following command:

```bash
git config --list
```

Answer (score -1):

To simply overcome this issue it is better to use an ssh key instead http/https

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

The main difference is that HTTP/HTTPS requires user name password pair and when they change or in case you forget them you need to re-set them.

With ssh you save this inconvenience